# AWK to Consolidate Files

Tags: awk

I'm hacking some AWK. I'm a beginner with it. I **have** done my homework on the following problem, and just can't get it to work.

### RAW DATA SAMPLE:

```
Start Date  12/3/17
End Date    12/30/17
Report Type Report1
Currency    ZAR
Country Identifier  MType   Quantity    Net Net Net Code    Title   Contrib I_Type  M_Type  Vendor Identifier   Offline Indicator   LSN
ZA  44057330    FMP 1   0.050666    0.050666    USYYYYYYYYYY    ABC Tom 1   1   USYYYYYYYYYY    0   SUT
ZA  1267456726  SIMT    1   0.03    0.03    USXXXXXXXXXX    DEF Frances 1   1   USXXXXXXXXXX    0   XYZ
Row Count   657
Storefront Name MType   Quantity    Net Net
ZA  FMP 601 30.45
ZA  IAP 13  0.68
ZA  IMP 1035    69.36
ZA  SIMP    54  1.4
ZA  FMT 70  0.53
ZA  IMT 92  1.68
ZA  SIMT    6   0.18
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT:

(I left the special characters un-escaped here.)

```
"Filename"  "Start Date"    "End Date"  "Currency"  "Country"   "Identifier"    "MType" "Quantity"  "Net"   "NetNet"    "Code"  "Title" "Contrib"   "I_Type"    "M_Type"    "Vendor Identifier" "Offline Indicator" "LSN"
"rawfile.txt"   "12/3/17"   "12/30/17"  "ZAR"   "ZA"    "44057330"  "FMP"   "1" "0.050666"  "0.050666"  "USYYYYYYYYYY"  "ABC"   "Tom"   "1" "1" "USYYYYYYYYYY"  "0" "SUT"
"rawfile.txt"   "12/3/17"   "12/30/17"  "ZAR"   "ZA"    "1267456726"    "SIMT"  "1" "0.03"  "0.03"  "USXXXXXXXXXX"  "DEF"   "Frances"   "1" "1" "USXXXXXXXXXX"  "0" "XYZ"
```

Basically I just need to get most of the header from line 5, but three fields I need are in lines 1-4. Also, I don't need the data including and after the line that starts with "Row Count".

### MY BEST "GUESS" SO FAR:

```
gawk '
function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }
  /^Row Count/ {nextfile}
  FNR == 1 { StartDate=$2; }
  FNR == 2 { EndDate=$2; }
  FNR == 4 { curr=$2; }
  NR == 5 {$0 = "StartDate" OFS "EndDate" OFS "Filename" OFS "curr" OFS $0; print} 
  FNR > 5 {$0 =  StartDate OFS EndDate OFS basename(FILENAME) OFS curr OFS $0; print}
' OFS='\t' path/to/sourcefiles/*.txt > path/to/outfile.txt
```

Thanks!

## EDITS:

### NEW TABLE

These are the lines before the field headers in every file. Content begins on line 4:

```
Provider ,,,,,,,,,,,,
01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

### "MY" SCRIPT

It almost works. But it includes lines 1-3 for every file:
    gawk '
    function basename(file) {
        sub(".*/", "", file)
        return file
      }
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR < 3 {
        if ( NR == 2 ) {
            hdr = "Report_Period" OFS
            val = val $1 OFS
        }
        next
    }
    FNR>3 {
        print "Filename", hdr $0
        next
    }
    { print basename(FILENAME), val $0 }
    ' OFS="," /path/to/input/files > ~/path/to/output/file/file.csv

End of edit

Comment: Are those `\t`s in "Raw Data Example" **really** present or are they supposed to represent tab characters? Are there **really** backslashes before every forward slash in the dates? Please make sure your posted sample input is exactly the format of input you want parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample input format isn't clear but this might be what you're looking for or it might be doing more than necessary or something else entirely:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
/^Row Count/ { nextfile }
FNR==1 {
    fname = FILENAME
    sub(/.*[/]/,"",fname)
}
{
    gsub(/[\\]t/,FS)
    gsub(/[\\][/]/,"/")
    gsub(/[^\t]+/,"\"&\"")
}
FNR < 5 {
    if ( FNR != 3 ) {
        hdr = hdr $1 OFS
        val = val $2 OFS
    }
    next
}
FNR==5 {
    print "\"Filename\"", hdr $0
    next
}
{ print "\""fname"\"", val $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"Filename"      "Start Date"    "End Date"      "Currency"      "Country"       "Identifier"    "MType" "Quantity"   "Net"    "Net Net"       "Code"  "Title" "Contrib"       "I_Type"        "M_Type"        "Vendor Identifier"     "Offline Indicator"   "LSN"
"file"  "12/3/17"       "12/30/17"      "ZAR"   "ZA"    "44057330"      "FMP"   "1"     "0.050666"      "0.050666"   "USYYYYYYYYYY"   "ABC"   "Tom"   "1"     "1"     "USYYYYYYYYYY"  "0"     "SUT"
"file"  "12/3/17"       "12/30/17"      "ZAR"   "ZA"    "1267456726"    "SIMT"  "1"     "0.03"  "0.03"  "USXXXXXXXXXX""DEF"   "Frances"       "1"     "1"     "USXXXXXXXXXX"  "0"     "XYZ"
```

The above uses GNU awk for nextfile, which you were already using.

Comment: Thanks Ed. That worked. You're right about the sample data -- I was just trying to make it easier for someone to cut-paste with escaped special characters. Anyway, I went back and changed it per your suggestion, for any future readers of this post. (Now I have to go back and try to figure out HOW & WHY that worked, so I can learn from it.)

Comment: Ed: the gsub section, if you will, is only because I had the escape characters in my sample, correct?

Comment: It converts the `\t` strings to tab chars and converts the `\/` strings to `/` chars so yes for those, and then it wraps every field in double quotes which is required regardless of the first 2 steps.

Comment: perfect; thanks. that's what I figured. the actual raw data doesn't have those escapes, so I'll edit the regex accordingly. this is how we learn! :)

Comment: Quick follow-up question? I just tried to apply the same logic to a different set of files. the "body" of those files is essentially the same as the ones in my sample. But the header rows look like the NEW table in my edited OP. I put the script I tried immediately after that new table.

Comment: Please post a new followup question with it's own sample input/output. This time please just post what the file contains, not some other characters that you think might help describe the input better or whatever it was that led you to put backslashes before forward slashes, etc. in this question. Make sure to indent your code input, and output 4 spaces so it's formatted correctly for display.

Comment: Done. I hope I did it "right". I don't really know the etiquette; I just make my best guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181188/awk-to-consolidate-files-follow-up

Comment: It's not bad, just needs some tidying up. See my comments under it.