# AWK to Consolidate Files (Follow-Up)

Tags: awk

Followup to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144323/awk-to-consolidate-files):
*(updated as requested in Comments)*

I started over with *actual* (disguised) sample data, and the results of running the script *on that data*.

### RAW DATA SAMPLE:

The headers & first two lines of the first two files in the directory. They are the same data, which is not a mistake. (It can happen in this dataset.)

#### File 1:

```
Provider,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15
B002H5QQJA,803814064988,803814064988,P2IIPDM5MDTW,P2IIPDM5MDTW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,YDtAK,BrandX
B002H5QQTU,803814064988,803814064988,K59C4XR93JOV,K59C4XR93JOV,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,kmAnC,BrandX
B002H5QR44,803814064988,803814064988,FUBOROFTLW9U,FUBOROFTLW9U,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,JdLye,BrandX
B002H5QRBC,803814064988,803814064988,KMHRXLF2FRKH,KMHRXLF2FRKH,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,Biqvo,BrandX
B002H5QSC0,803814064988,803814064988,PCLB5UPGGP9T,PCLB5UPGGP9T,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar2,Iwvhe,BrandX
B002H5QU3M,505545471538,505545471538,3K4GDYDEOH1M,3K4GDYDEOH1M,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar3,NWsOC,BrandY
B002H5QUAK,417248985349,417248985349,7R40MN9AD9I8,7R40MN9AD9I8,T,Prod_I,1,0,1,0,foo4,bar4,YVQeH,BrandY
B002H5QUBY,417248985349,417248985349,C04GQONG1Z5B,C04GQONG1Z5B,T,Prod_I,1,0,1,0,foo4,bar4,PERMW,BrandY
B002H5QUCI,505545471538,505545471538,4E1ZGIJR1GPR,4E1ZGIJR1GPR,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar3,UycEB,BrandY
B002H5QUVO,804699101426,804699101426,51RXKMWGJJ30,51RXKMWGJJ30,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar5,Qwyuy,BrandY
B002H5QUZ0,804699101426,804699101426,7L0QBQM8S80L,7L0QBQM8S80L,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar5,nqgId,BrandY
B002H5QXF2,803814064988,803814064988,PH0Q5QI34B0R,PH0Q5QI34B0R,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo6,bar6,hPFiY,BrandX
B002H5QXWK,803814064988,803814064988,PSCLFNIDVZS0,PSCLFNIDVZS0,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo6,bar6,BCdzF,BrandX
```

#### File 2:

```
Provider,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15
B002H5N3AA,245462777033,245462777033,CFFWR2KSWLR8,CFFWR2KSWLR8,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar1,foo2,bar1,RkG7D,BrandY
B002H5N3IM,245462777033,245462777033,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar1,foo2,bar1,jqiGj,BrandY
B002H5N3R8,245462777033,245462777033,8ZNJHVCVO0A1,8ZNJHVCVO0A1,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar1,foo2,bar1,Ylrcy,BrandY
B002H5N6X4,766193337142,766193337142,37YX24TRDPNW,37YX24TRDPNW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar2,foo3,bar2,WHxLZ,BrandX
B002H5N756,766193337142,766193337142,H56J19KCLFZP,H56J19KCLFZP,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar2,foo3,bar2,VVw34,BrandX
B002H5N8QO,73612604823,73612604823,HZC9P776G2EP,HZC9P776G2EP,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar3,foo4,bar3,X48HD,BrandZ
B002H5NA3U,932053704970,932053704970,XFIB2V8RQXN4,XFIB2V8RQXN4,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar4,foo5,bar4,ghftn,BrandY
B002H5NJ6S,245675038659,245675038659,MUCSMOR5HB7V,MUCSMOR5HB7V,T,Prod_I,11,2,1,0,bar5,foo6,bar5,TVY19,BrandX
B002H5NJ6S,245675038659,245675038659,MUCSMOR5HB7V,MUCSMOR5HB7V,T,Prod_P,,,,2,bar5,foo6,bar5,M2j1i,BrandX
B002H5NJXQ,73612604823,73612604823,RJER36PXDF0T,RJER36PXDF0T,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar6,foo7,bar6,1UnN3,BrandY
B002H5OU5C,491559514618,491559514618,X9K6BVZEHDDZ,X9K6BVZEHDDZ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar7,foo8,bar7,eybpO,BrandX
B002H5OU66,491559514618,491559514618,6510BKD3XD9R,6510BKD3XD9R,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar7,foo8,bar7,yS9xk,BrandX
B002H5OU6Q,491559514618,491559514618,EFWDVP7FPCFA,EFWDVP7FPCFA,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar7,foo8,bar7,0IXqS,BrandX
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Filename,Report_Period,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QQJA,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,P2IIPDM5MDTW,P2IIPDM5MDTW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,YDtAK,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QQTU,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,K59C4XR93JOV,K59C4XR93JOV,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,kmAnC,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QR44,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,FUBOROFTLW9U,FUBOROFTLW9U,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,JdLye,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QRBC,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,KMHRXLF2FRKH,KMHRXLF2FRKH,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,Biqvo,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QSC0,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,PCLB5UPGGP9T,PCLB5UPGGP9T,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar2,Iwvhe,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QU3M,5.05545E+11,5.06E+11,3K4GDYDEOH1M,3K4GDYDEOH1M,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar3,NWsOC,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QUAK,4.17249E+11,4.17E+11,7R40MN9AD9I8,7R40MN9AD9I8,T,Prod_I,1,0,1,0,foo4,bar4,YVQeH,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QUBY,4.17249E+11,4.17E+11,C04GQONG1Z5B,C04GQONG1Z5B,T,Prod_I,1,0,1,0,foo4,bar4,PERMW,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QUCI,5.05545E+11,5.06E+11,4E1ZGIJR1GPR,4E1ZGIJR1GPR,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar3,UycEB,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QUVO,8.04699E+11,8.05E+11,51RXKMWGJJ30,51RXKMWGJJ30,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar5,Qwyuy,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QUZ0,8.04699E+11,8.05E+11,7L0QBQM8S80L,7L0QBQM8S80L,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar5,nqgId,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QXF2,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,PH0Q5QI34B0R,PH0Q5QI34B0R,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo6,bar6,hPFiY,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QXWK,8.03814E+11,8.04E+11,PSCLFNIDVZS0,PSCLFNIDVZS0,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo6,bar6,BCdzF,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5N3AA,2.45463E+11,2.45E+11,CFFWR2KSWLR8,CFFWR2KSWLR8,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar1,RkG7D,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5N3IM,2.45463E+11,2.45E+11,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar1,jqiGj,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5N3R8,2.45463E+11,2.45E+11,8ZNJHVCVO0A1,8ZNJHVCVO0A1,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar1,Ylrcy,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5N6X4,7.66193E+11,7.66E+11,37YX24TRDPNW,37YX24TRDPNW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar2,WHxLZ,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5N756,7.66193E+11,7.66E+11,H56J19KCLFZP,H56J19KCLFZP,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar2,VVw34,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5N8QO,73612604823,73612604823,HZC9P776G2EP,HZC9P776G2EP,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo4,bar3,X48HD,BrandZ
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5NA3U,9.32054E+11,9.32E+11,XFIB2V8RQXN4,XFIB2V8RQXN4,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar4,ghftn,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5NJ6S,2.45675E+11,2.46E+11,MUCSMOR5HB7V,MUCSMOR5HB7V,T,Prod_I,11,2,1,0,foo6,bar5,TVY19,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5NJ6S,2.45675E+11,2.46E+11,MUCSMOR5HB7V,MUCSMOR5HB7V,T,Prod_P,,,,2,foo6,bar5,M2j1i,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5NJXQ,73612604823,73612604823,RJER36PXDF0T,RJER36PXDF0T,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo7,bar6,1UnN3,BrandY
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5OU5C,4.9156E+11,4.92E+11,X9K6BVZEHDDZ,X9K6BVZEHDDZ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo8,bar7,eybpO,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5OU66,4.9156E+11,4.92E+11,6510BKD3XD9R,6510BKD3XD9R,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo8,bar7,yS9xk,BrandX
FILENAME,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5OU6Q,4.9156E+11,4.92E+11,EFWDVP7FPCFA,EFWDVP7FPCFA,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo8,bar7,0IXqS,BrandX
```

### MY SCRIPT (Adapted from the accepted answer in my O.P.):

It almost works. But it includes lines 1-3 for every file:

```
gawk '
function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR < 3 {
    if ( NR == 2 ) {
        hdr = "Report_Period" OFS
        val = val $1 OFS
    }
    next
}
FNR>3 {
    print "Filename", hdr $0
    next
}
{ print basename(FILENAME), val $0 }
' OFS="," /path/to/input/files/*.csv > ~/path/to/output/file/SampleOutput.csv
```

### ACTUAL OUTPUT

This is the entire contents of the result file. The problem seems to be that the headers are repeating:

```
Sample1.csv,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QQJA,803814064988,803814064988,P2IIPDM5MDTW,P2IIPDM5MDTW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,YDtAK,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QQTU,803814064988,803814064988,K59C4XR93JOV,K59C4XR93JOV,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,kmAnC,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QR44,803814064988,803814064988,FUBOROFTLW9U,FUBOROFTLW9U,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,JdLye,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QRBC,803814064988,803814064988,KMHRXLF2FRKH,KMHRXLF2FRKH,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,Biqvo,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QSC0,803814064988,803814064988,PCLB5UPGGP9T,PCLB5UPGGP9T,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar2,Iwvhe,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QU3M,505545471538,505545471538,3K4GDYDEOH1M,3K4GDYDEOH1M,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar3,NWsOC,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QUAK,417248985349,417248985349,7R40MN9AD9I8,7R40MN9AD9I8,T,Prod_I,1,0,1,0,foo4,bar4,YVQeH,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QUBY,417248985349,417248985349,C04GQONG1Z5B,C04GQONG1Z5B,T,Prod_I,1,0,1,0,foo4,bar4,PERMW,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QUCI,505545471538,505545471538,4E1ZGIJR1GPR,4E1ZGIJR1GPR,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar3,UycEB,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QUVO,804699101426,804699101426,51RXKMWGJJ30,51RXKMWGJJ30,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar5,Qwyuy,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QUZ0,804699101426,804699101426,7L0QBQM8S80L,7L0QBQM8S80L,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar5,nqgId,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QXF2,803814064988,803814064988,PH0Q5QI34B0R,PH0Q5QI34B0R,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo6,bar6,hPFiY,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5QXWK,803814064988,803814064988,PSCLFNIDVZS0,PSCLFNIDVZS0,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo6,bar6,BCdzF,BrandX
Sample2.csv,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,Provider,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Sample2.csv,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Sample2.csv,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5N3AA,2.45463E+11,2.45463E+11,CFFWR2KSWLR8,CFFWR2KSWLR8,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar1,RkG7D,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5N3IM,2.45463E+11,2.45463E+11,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar1,jqiGj,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5N3R8,2.45463E+11,2.45463E+11,8ZNJHVCVO0A1,8ZNJHVCVO0A1,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo2,bar1,Ylrcy,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5N6X4,7.66193E+11,7.66193E+11,37YX24TRDPNW,37YX24TRDPNW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar2,WHxLZ,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5N756,7.66193E+11,7.66193E+11,H56J19KCLFZP,H56J19KCLFZP,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo3,bar2,VVw34,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5N8QO,73612604823,73612604823,HZC9P776G2EP,HZC9P776G2EP,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo4,bar3,X48HD,BrandZ
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5NA3U,9.32054E+11,9.32054E+11,XFIB2V8RQXN4,XFIB2V8RQXN4,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo5,bar4,ghftn,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5NJ6S,2.45675E+11,2.45675E+11,MUCSMOR5HB7V,MUCSMOR5HB7V,T,Prod_I,11,2,1,0,foo6,bar5,TVY19,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5NJ6S,2.45675E+11,2.45675E+11,MUCSMOR5HB7V,MUCSMOR5HB7V,T,Prod_P,,,,2,foo6,bar5,M2j1i,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5NJXQ,73612604823,73612604823,RJER36PXDF0T,RJER36PXDF0T,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo7,bar6,1UnN3,BrandY
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5OU5C,4.9156E+11,4.9156E+11,X9K6BVZEHDDZ,X9K6BVZEHDDZ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo8,bar7,eybpO,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5OU66,4.9156E+11,4.9156E+11,6510BKD3XD9R,6510BKD3XD9R,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo8,bar7,yS9xk,BrandX
Filename,Report_Period,B002H5OU6Q,4.9156E+11,4.9156E+11,EFWDVP7FPCFA,EFWDVP7FPCFA,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo8,bar7,0IXqS,BrandX
```

Thanks (again)!

Comment: Clean up what you can yourself (e.g. you want a header named "Period" but you're adding a string "Report_Period", you set OFS in the BEGIN section and then again after the script, and you showed us NR but must be using FNR for the symptoms described). Now take a look at the change you made to convert the hdr assignment line from your previous script (`hdr = hdr $1 OFS`) to this script (`hdr = "Report_Period" OFS`) and think about what those 2 lines are actually doing when executed for every one of the first 3 lines. Finally consider what `FNR < 3` actually means wrt `it includes lines 1-3`

Comment: Basically just make sure that the script you post is **the** script you're having trouble with and produces the symptoms you describe. Also, if you're running it with multiple input files then **show that** by including at least 2 sample input files, the associated expected output, and the associated correct call to awk (right now you're passing it 1 input file).

Comment: Thanks again, Ed. It's going to take me a little while to get through that. I'm really new at awk. (And I've been working very long hours.) But I'll figure out every bit of your suggestion, then try it, and update the post accordingly.

Comment: Make sure your posted desired output is **the exact output** that you expect to get from the input files you posted. Posting sample input and then output that can't be derived from the input isn't useful.

Comment: I can't really do that, Ed. The data is sensitive, so I have to disguise it. And I don't know how to do that without it becoming a project in itself. So I'll keep hacking at what you've already given me, and see if I can eventually crack it. Thanks for all the help, though. Believe it or not, I've already learned a bunch from this example.

Comment: Of course you can do that. Just make up strings like foo, bar, johnny, freda, 12637, etc. and use those. Or make then file1line1field1, file1line1field2 ... file2line2field1, file2line2field2, etc. if imagination fails you.You only need a couple of lines, each of 2 or 3 fields per file - it'll take you about 10 minutes. Glad to hear you're getting some benefit!

Comment: well, it wasn't exactly *easy*, but I've updated the post with real (disguised) data. :)

Comment: But why post all of that data when you can describe the problem with a fraction of it? I for one am definitely not going to wade through all of that data trying to figure out which fields from the input are being mapped to which fields of the output and I suspect others won't either. When posting a question you should create a [mcve] (emphasis on **Minimal**) that demonstrates just **the problem**, it doesn't have to be as massive as your real world data as no-one wants to read through piles of completely irrelevant data. See [ask].

Comment: Get it down to where each input file has less than 5 rows of less than 5 fields each and then I expect someone will look at it.

Comment: Thanks again, Ed. Next time I'll know from the outset how to structure my sample data. I really do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try two. Forgot to include the header.

```
(pi 580) $ cat /tmp/x.sh
#!/bin/sh

gawk '
  BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
  FNR == 1 {file=FILENAME; sub(".*/", "", file); next}
  FNR == 2 {period=$1; next}
  NR  == 3 {print "file","period",$0; next}
  FNR == 3 {next}
  {print file,period,$0}
' $*

(pi 581) $ /tmp/x.sh /tmp/f?.*
file,period,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field9,Field10,Field11,Field12,Field13,Field14,Field15
f1.txt,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QQJA,803814064988,803814064988,P2IIPDM5MDTW,P2IIPDM5MDTW,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,YDtAK,BrandX
f1.txt,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,B002H5QQTU,803814064988,803814064988,K59C4XR93JOV,K59C4XR93JOV,T,Prod_P,,,,1,foo1,bar1,kmAnC,BrandX
f2.txt,01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,B002H5N3AA,245462777033,245462777033,CFFWR2KSWLR8,CFFWR2KSWLR8,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar1,foo2,bar1,RkG7D,BrandY
f2.txt,01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,B002H5N3IM,245462777033,245462777033,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,CYFTO0FGAPSJ,T,Prod_P,,,,1,bar1,foo2,bar1,jqiGj,BrandY
```

Comment: Just noticed you used FNR. Anyways, this works and I think is a bit cleaner logic.

Comment: too much coffee this morning. ugh. Nth try.

Comment: Thanks Keith. That did work. Now by comparing this & Ed's answers, I can learn ever more about how awk works.

Comment: Our answers are essentially the same, though he does his with fewer tests. :)

Comment: Yeah, if I'd read your first I wouldn't have bothered with mine but when I started creating the sample data to use in mine you hadn't posted yet and by the time I was done and posted it then saw yours, I didn't see the point of just throwing it away since it had the sample data in it and showed an alternative structure. You have a bug at `period=1` btw.

Comment: BTW, questions/answers like this make me remember just how clever 'A,' 'W,' and 'K' are.

Comment: IMHO by far the most impressive thing about awk is how the maintainers of all awk variants have stuck to the original language concept of only introducing language constructs to do things that are difficult to do otherwise. The result is a tiny, simple, yet extremely powerful language devoid of the code bloat that all other text processing tools have incurred. Very impressive IMHO.

Comment: I notice that I have perl 5, version 2x, on my hosts. I guess I made the right decision to not get that perl 6 book years ago.

Comment: I'm proud to say I caught that bug where period=1. I literally started 12 months ago with zero programming knowledge, and I'm just finishing up a full-blown app in R that extracts raw data from about 7K source files, all with different structures and delimiters. Most of what I learned was in R, but I did have to prop it up with some command line stuff for ETL. Again, I started from zero knowledge. Here's an ***interactive*** graph (click-drag to spin, scroll to zoom) of the database: http://www.mvabl.com/projects/UFO/RB_network.html. THANKS GUYS!

Comment: @Steve - nice! Check out "https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045" for another cool tool for displaying graphs (2D). Used it for my thesis a couple of years ago.

Comment: oh, I'm familiar with mike bostock's work. I use it for inspiration sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==3 {
    print "Filename", "Report_Period", $0
}
FNR==2 {
    fname = FILENAME
    sub(".*/","",fname)
    period = $1
}
FNR>3 {
    print fname, period, $0
}
```

I made up my own data to test it (file#_row#_col#):

```
$ cat file1
Provider,,
02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,,
Field1,Field2,Field3
f1_r1_c1,f1_r1_c2,f1_r1_c3
f1_r2_c1,f1_r2_c2,f1_r2_c3

$ cat file2
Provider,,
01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,,
Field1,Field2,Field3
f2_r1_c1,f2_r1_c2,f2_r1_c3
f2_r2_c1,f2_r2_c2,f2_r2_c3

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Filename,Report_Period,Field1,Field2,Field3
file1,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,f1_r1_c1,f1_r1_c2,f1_r1_c3
file1,02/01/2018 - 02/28/2018,f1_r2_c1,f1_r2_c2,f1_r2_c3
file2,01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,f2_r1_c1,f2_r1_c2,f2_r1_c3
file2,01/01/2018 - 01/31/2018,f2_r2_c1,f2_r2_c2,f2_r2_c3
```

If that's not what you want then please edit your question to clarify your requirements and use minimal sample input/output.